# Tornar imagem responsiva no Delphi

Tags: delphi, imagem

Estou em um projeto e preciso colocar uma imagem de fundo, gostaria de deixar essa imagem responsiva porem não estou conseguindo. Estou usando o `Timage` para inserir a imagem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem duas formas de fazer, em *design time* ou por *código*, vamos a primeira opção.

Design Time:

Tal como mencionado pelo @lucaswmolin, clica no component `TImage` e nas propriedades vai definir primeiro de tudo a imagem em `picture` depois vamos tornar o componente responsivo definindo `alclient` para a propriedade `align`, de seguida na opção `Stretch` definimos como `True` para tornar a imagem que abrir com o tamanho igual ao componente. Como pode ver na imagem abaixo: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

Por código basta utilizar o seguinte exemplo no `onCreate` do form:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //vai abrir a imagem 
  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('caminho');
  //define o tamanho do componente ao form 
  Image1.Align := AlClient;
  //defini o tamanho da imagem ao componente
  Image1.Stretch := True;
end;
```

**EDIT1:**

---

Após o comentário do @MuriloPecht que na versão Delphi 10.2 não estava a funcionar fui testar e na verdade não funciona se o projecto criado for um "Multi-Device Application" os passos para a imagem ficar a funcionar são os seguinte:

**1º** Copiar um Timage para o form
**2º** Nas *properties* define `client` para a opção `align`.
**3º** Nas *properties* opção MultiRestBitmap clica nos 3 pontos e vamos carregar o caminho da imagem, veja na imagem abaixo onde carregar o caminho:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para usar a opção por código, basta usar o seguinte:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //vai abrir a imagem 
  Image1.MultiResBitmap[0].bitmap.LoadFromFile('caminho');
  //define o tamanho do componente ao form 
  Image1.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
end;
```

Comment: então amigo, eu adicionei o Timage porem não encontrei em propriedades o elemento picture para ser alterado.

Comment: mesmo quando adiciono o elemento Timage e adiciono no oncreate do form a linha: Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile('caminho'); o Delphi fala que "does not contain a member named 'Picture'."

Comment: @MuriloPecht editei a resposta com uma foto da localização da propriedade, basta clicar nos 3 pontos e acrescentar a imagem

Comment: não tem essa propriedade porque estou utilizando o delphi 10.2 tokyo.

Comment: então, ainda não consegui resolver, pois a resposta que vc me mandou é para o delphi 2010, e eu estou usando o delphi 10.2 tokyo.

Comment: @MuriloPecht vou pesquisar um pouco e editar a minha resposta se conseguir

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: @MuriloPecht que tipo de projecto está a criar? vcl forms application, multi-device application,.... poderia me dizer para o poder ajudar a resolver o seu problema?

Comment: muito obrigado, me ajudou muito.